# How to read last line of file, and store an increment to that file again?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <ostream>

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void sav(long int num);

int main(){


    long int accnum;
        ifstream in;
        in.open("(filename).txt",ios::in);
        in>>accnum; 
        accnum++;
        in.close();
        sav(accnum);
        cout<<accnum;

}



void sav(long int num){


        ofstream in;
        in.open("(filename).txt",ios::in|ios::app);
        in<<"\n";
        in<<num;
        in.setf(ios::fixed);
        in<<setprecision(0);
        in.close();

}
```

if (filename).txt has first line as integer 4332

second line integer 4333

while running program again, it calls the first line and increment it

and store the second line as third line. repeats the same if run 3 times.

example: in filename.txt while program is run 3 times is shows below:-

4332

4333

4333

4333

4333

the func. void sav(long int num) to write new value in filename.txt works perfectly fine.

i except my result in filename.txt to be show below as:-

4332

4333

4334

4335

4336

my question is how will i call the last line so i can increment it?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530274/how-to-overwrite-only-part-of-a-file-in-c).

Comment: The simplest way to read the last line of a file is to read all the lines in a loop, and only remember the last one.

Comment: Thank you all very much! i appreciate the help!! Thanks again!!!